# How to update a column with values from the same newly inserted row in a trigger?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, trigger, update

Using SQL Server 2014, I have this:

```
Table1
Tab1_id        int identity(1,1) primary key
Tab1_val1      smallint
Tab1_val2      smallint
Tab1_valInfo   varchar(10) -- not yet implemented, will be used only for presentation
```

```
 Tab1_id |   Tab1_val1 |   Tab1_val2 | Tab1_valInfo
---------|-------------|-------------|--------------
       1 |          25 |          19 | 0025-0019
       2 |           0 |           5 | 0000-0005
       3 |          12 |           3 | 0012-0003
```

Now with my pretty short SQL experience, what I'm trying is:

From an application where the only input values required for inserting data are `Tab1_val1` and `Tab1_val2`, then, create a trigger which updates `Tab1_valInfo` column.

```
create trigger utr_ValInfo on Table1
after insert as
begin

    declare @size int = 4;

    declare @valInfo varchar(10) =
        select right('0000' + convert(varchar, /* insertedRow.Tab1_val1 */), @size) from inserted
        + '-' +
        select right('0000' + convert(varchar, /* insertedRow.Tab1_val2 */), @size) from inserted;

    update Table1 set Tab1_valInfo = @valInfo where /* this is the last inserted row*/;

end;
```

A single insert may involve multiple rows.

I hope what I'm trying to achieve is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try Computed column rather than triggers, since its easy to modify .
Try below query

```
create table tab_computed 
(
Tab1_id        int identity(1,1) primary key,

Tab1_val1      smallint,

Tab1_val2      smallint,

Tab1_valInfo   as (right('0000' + convert(varchar,Tab1_val1), 4)+ '-' + right('0000' + convert(varchar,Tab1_val2), 4)) 
 ) 

insert into tab_computed 
(Tab1_val1,Tab1_val2) values (25,19),(0,5),(12,3)

select * from tab_computed
```

Result set :

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
create trigger utr_ValInfo on Table1
after insert as
begin

    declare @size int = 4;

    UPDATE Table1 

    SET 
         Tab1_valInfo  = right('0000' + convert(varchar, i.Tab1_val1), @size) 
            + '-' +
             right('0000' + convert(varchar, i.Tab1_val2), @size)

    FROM Inserted i

    WHERE 
         Table1.Tab1_id= i.Tab1_id;
end;
```

and [don't declare varchar in convert without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)